# Merge subarrays of different lengths PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dynamically built array that looks like so:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "169135"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "168917"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "172168"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(123) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "171169"
  } [3]=>
    array(123) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "171129"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "172768"
    }
}
```

But instead would like to combine all the subarrays like so:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "169135"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "168917"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "172168"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(123) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "171169"
     }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["rhID"]=>
      string(6) "172768"
    }
  }    
}
```

Note that I never know how many subarrays I will have. Could be 1 or 2 or 7. Excuse me if I forgot a bracked or so I was quickly editing in notepad.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $entry) {
        $newArray[] = $entry;
    }
}
```

It's as easy as that.

Comment: @bwoebi I would have done the same after reviewing your initial post, it's just good practice to correctly open and close a `foreach` loop

Comment: @DarylGill okay... For me it's only line waste (a \n after it is enough for me)

Comment: It's not a waste of lines, it's a) sticking to standards and more importantly b) making code more readable by giving the brain visual support on how to group and arrange what's read. In other words it's called usability.